# Firebase Text Recognition for Web

Tags: javascript, firebase-machine-learning

Is it possible to use Text Recognition (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/recognize-text) for web projects. I'd like it to run the built-in model through images uploaded to the Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml):

> Firebase Machine Learning is a mobile SDK that brings Google's machine learning expertise to **Android and Apple apps** in a powerful yet easy-to-use package.

So it seems that Firebase Machine Learning is only available for Android and iOS apps, and not for web apps.